# what adt importer does when we import eclipse project in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to know what tasks ADT import does when we import any android eclipse project in android studio.

Comment: Copy sources and generates the appropriate `build.gradle` based on your dependencies and file structure.

Comment: Not to forget the heavy modifications to the structure of the source tree, causing most of your stuff to end up in a new place.